# Documentation (not examples) of Clarifai Python gRPC interface

Tags: clarifai

Anyone point me to where there is documentation (not examples) of the calls ? Such as service_pb2.PostInputsRequest() ? Parameter lists ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for Clarifai python API: https://sdk.clarifai.com/python/docs/latest/clarifai.rest.html#inputs